# FB XFBML parse callback triggered early in IE11

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've developed a page that shows dinamically a list of [facebook embedded posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts).

I call `FB.XFBML.parse(document, onRenderCompleted)` to trigger FB SDK to load embedded posts and to be notified at the rendering completed ([FB.XFBML.parse documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse))

Unexpectedly, in IE11 the callback is invoked before all elements are rendered. Instead it works like a charm in Chrome e Firefox.

I've created a plunkr to reproduce it
https://plnkr.co/edit/t04YzRbOCz3qK1nweE0m?p=preview

any help?

Comment: Apart from filing a bug report and asking Facebook if they can fix this, there likely isn’t much you can do. I came across this myself recently, we wanted to display posts in combination with masonry, and therefor had to wait until all the iframes are loaded. Worked fine in other browsers, but not in IE - we eventually called masonry again from within the event handler with a timeout of one second for IE, that _kinda_ fixed it. (Not a perfect solution of course, and depending on connection speed etc. it might still fail in some situations.)

Comment: Yes, I've adopted this workaround me too. I'll report bug to FB. I opened question also here, because I can't think I could the first to detect a such evident bug in a such used SDK. I supposed a misunderstanding in documentation or not right use. Thanks for feedback.